# MySQL syntax issue, multiple SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I am working of a project that has 2 tables as follows: **users_fb** and **posts**

*I spent 3 hours playing with the code and then I gave up.*

table: posts

```
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| id  | by_user | by_page |  votes  | status  |    time   |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
|   1 |       1 |       0 |      20 |       1 | 372041014 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

table: users_fb

```
+-----+-----------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| id  | username  | name  | gender  | fb_id  | email |
+-----+-----------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

---

```
SELECT username, 
        (
        SELECT      COUNT(b.by_user)
        FROM        users_fb a LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.id = b.by_user
        WHERE       b.by_page = '0'
        GROUP BY    a.username
        ) AS totalCount ,
        (
        SELECT      IFNULL(SUM(b.votes),0)
        FROM        users_fb a LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.id = b.by_user
        GROUP BY    users_fb.id
        ) AS total_votes
        FROM users_fb ORDER BY  total_votes DESC
```

**The desired output**

```
+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|     username      | totalCount  | total_votes |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
| user4             |          1  |          25 |
| user1             |          0  |          0  |
| user2             |          0  |          0  |
| user3             |          0  |          0  |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**UNFORTUNATELY: This is what I am getting**

```
+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|     username      | totalCount  | total_votes |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
| user4             |          1  |          25 |
| user1             |          1  |          25 |
| user2             |          1  |          25 |
| user3             |          1  |          25 |
+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

If you need any further information, let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show your data?

Comment: you mean the table structure?

Comment: your table structure with some sample data

Comment: alright, I have added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have anything to join your tables together to match up with posts / votes go with which user.

Something like this should do it

```
SELECT users_fb.username, Sub1.postcount, Sub2.votecount
FROM users_fb
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT      a.username, COUNT(*) AS postcount
    FROM        users_fb a 
    INNER JOIN posts b 
    ON a.id = b.by_user
    WHERE       b.by_page = '0'
    GROUP BY    a.username
) Sub1
ON users_fb.username = Sub1.username
LEFT OUTER JOIN(        
    SELECT      users_fb.id, IFNULL(SUM(b.votes),0) AS votecount
    FROM        users_fb a 
    LEFT JOIN posts b 
    ON a.id = b.by_user
    GROUP BY    users_fb.id
) Sub2
ON users_fb.id = Sub2.id
```

Possibly simplified to

```
SELECT      a.username, SUM(IF(b.by_page = '0', 1, 0)) AS postcount, IFNULL(SUM(b.votes),0) AS votecount
FROM        users_fb a 
LEFT JOIN posts b 
ON a.id = b.by_user
GROUP BY    a.username
```

Comment: Thanks! The simplified code works perfectly, however, the other is showing me an error which is "#1054 - Unknown column 'Sub1.users_fb' in 'on clause'".

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixed now I think

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      a.username,
            COUNT(b.by_user) totalCount,
            SUM(IFNULL(b.votes,0)) total_votes
FROM        users_fb a 
            LEFT JOIN posts b 
ON a.id = b.by_user
WHERE       b.by_page = '0'
GROUP BY    a.id,a.username
```

Comment: This is missing the condition "b.by_page = '0'". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few problems, the biggest is that you don't make any join between your "main query" and your "subqueries".

So finally, something like that should be better.

```
SELECT
a.username,
SUM (CASE WHEN b.by_page IS NOT NULL and b.by_page = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt,
SUM (IFNULL(b.votes),0) as nbVotes,
FROM  users_fb a 
LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.id = b.by_user
GROUP BY    users_fb.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing no matching of the selects (i.e. there is no binding WHERE between them), MySQL has no wait to make them show together.

You should do something like this:

```
    SELECT username, totalCount.count, total_votesGROUPED.sum
    FROM users_fb
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT      COUNT(b.by_user) as count, a.username
       FROM        users_fb a LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.id = b.by_user
       WHERE       b.by_page = '0'
       GROUP BY    a.username
    ) AS totalCount ON totalCount.username = users_fb.username,
    (
       SELECT      IFNULL(SUM(b.votes),0) as sum, id
       FROM        users_fb a LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.id = b.by_user
       GROUP BY    users_fb.id
    ) AS total_votesGROUPED ON total_votesGROUPED.id = users_fb.id
    ORDER BY  total_votes DESC
```

If I had a bit more information, I could test it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username, IFNULL(COUNT(b.by_user), 0) totalCount, IFNULL(SUM(c.votes), 0) total_votes
FROM users_fb a
LEFT JOIN posts b
ON a.id = b.by_user AND b.by_page = 0
LEFT JOIN posts c
ON a.id = b.by_user
GROUP BY username
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49136/1)

Comment: Thanks! Although you put the condition b.by_page = 0, but it is not working.